# Enum to Int. Int to Enum . Best way to do conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

```
 public Enum Days
 {
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    Sunday = 7
 }
```

Now I wanted to know how do I get the integer value of an enum and convert an integer value into enum

Will

```
       int dayNo = (int) Days.Monday;
```

change the value of dayNo to 1;

and

Will

```
        Days day = (Days) 2;
```

assign Days.Tuesday to the variable day ??

How about is this the best way to do the parsing??

Comment: Are you unable to try it and see for yourself?

Comment: Casting should work. By the way there's already `DayOfWeek` enum in the BCL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will do exactly that except `Enum` should be `enum`

```
public enum Days
 {
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    Sunday = 7
 }
```

To use Enum.Parse you MUST provide a string so if you want to cast from the int you'd have to go via a string which is ugly.

```
Days x = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), "3");
Days y = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), 3.ToString());
```

... both give you wednesday.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and this is very easy to check:

```
Days d = (Days)3;
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

This will output

```
Wednesday
```

As a best practice, the name of your `enum` should be `Day` not `Days`; the variable `d` above represents a `Day` not `Days`. See the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, [yes](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/enum_coversion_operations_int_to_enum_enum_to_int_string_to_enum_enum_to_string.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of enums is correct.

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) to convert from number/name to enum type if you feel more comfortable with this method, but it gains nothing in readbility or performance.

Strangely, in order to parse numbers, you need to call `ToString()` on them first, as `Enum.Parse` has no integer overload.

From the MSDN page:

```
Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
```

Comment: thank you i just wanted to know if there was another way of doing the above except when parsing.

Comment: `Enum.Parse` does NOT convert from an `int` to the appropriate `enum` value. This answer is wrong or misleading at best.

Comment: @Jason - Going by the documentation, it does convert to an equivalent enumerated object.

Comment: A bit of a hair spliter, it will parse from a string rep of the int.
Days x = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), "3"); or
Days y = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), 3.ToString()); but not the int itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139420/enum-to-int-int-to-enum-best-way-to-do-conversion/2139465#2139465

Comment: @Oded: But there is no overload of `Enum.Parse` that has a parameter of type `int`.

Comment: @Jason - You are right and the documentation seems to be misleading. As you say, you need to call `ToString()` on an integer in order to use `Enum.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. But did you try it before posting?