# C# Overloading Enums To Store Values

Tags: c#, enums, unordered

I currently have an *enum* defined as follows:

```
public enum ColorEnum { Red, White, Blue, Green };
```

Each of these *enum* values has an underlying int value that I need to be able to return to the user. To do so, I wrote a function that takes in the *enum* and returns an *int*:

```
public int colorToValue(ColorEnum color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case Red:
            return 5;
        case White:
            return 10;
        case Blue:
            return 15;
        case Green:
            return 20;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works well and good but I was wondering if I could simplify things by using the *enum* itself to store the underlying values. For example, could I just define the *enum* as follows:

```
public enum ColorEnum { Red = 5, White = 10, Blue = 15, Green = 20 };
```

Then converting the *enum* to it's underlying value would be as simple as casting it to an int. The above function simplifies to the following:

```
public int colorToValue(ColorEnum color)
{
    return (int)color;
}
```

Of course, the values for *each* enum entry would have to be an *int* as required by the enum definition.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can do it, would have known if you had given it a try ! !

Comment: My question was kinda hidden.. it was in the middle part of my post.. _"I was wondering if I could simplify things by using the enum itself to store the underlying values"_

Comment: True, I could have just tried it out myself. But then I wouldn't be building a reputation on stackoverflow. :)))

Comment: @JanTacci: Then this question is [redundant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139420/enum-to-int-int-to-enum-best-way-to-do-conversion) since you really could have tested it yourself (i'm sure you have). It would have been a more interesting to know if this is good practise.

Comment: Okay okay, I will try to provide more answers than questions from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is entirely valid and will work fine. Enums cast cleanly to/from their underlying type, and it is very common for them to have prescribed values rather than just 1,2,3...

The only thing to watch, though, is that the reverse is true too. So this works fine:

```
ColorEnum evil = (ColorEnum)(-53); // why not...
```

Your *original* `colorToValue(evil)` code would return `0` for this; your new code will return `-53`. Personally I might have thrown an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

There is also an `Enum.IsDefined` method, but that involves *boxing* the value. But if you *do* want to check the input is an expected value, at least you can simplify:

```
public int colorToValue(ColorEnum color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case Red:
        case White:
        case Blue:
        case Green:
            return (int)color;
        default:
            return 0; // or throw, whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you subtract a number from the _enum_ definition (i.e. _ColorEnum_) or did you mean something like (_ColorEnum.Red_)-53? What is the value for _ColorEnum_ by itself? Zero?

Comment: @Jan I meant that to mean "cast -53 as a `ColorEnum`" - looks like I missed some parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: What is the value of the following statement.... _bool isBlue = (ColorEnum.Green-5==ColorEnum.Blue)_?

Comment: Also note that `0` (zero) is special in at least two ways. Firstly, the default value of your enum type will correspond to `0`. So if you choose to make one of your enum members equal to `0`, that member will, in a sense, be "special". If you choose not to make any member equal to `0`, then the default `ColorEnum` will be "unnamed". Secondly, the C# language allows the literal `0` to be **implicitly** cast to any enum type. So `ColorEnum c = 0;` will compile, where as `ColorEnum c = 5;` won't (needs cast).